# Single window mode with the ability to open multiple dialogs at once in PyQt5?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, pyside2, python-3.8

I'm using the below code in PyQt5/PySide2 in order to create a single mode window application, when I open a new dialog:

```
dialog.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
dialog.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool)
```

But I need another mode which I didn't managed to solve it by reading the docs, imagine we've got a QMainWindow and we have 4 buttons on the main window, I want to open the corresponding dialogs when clicking on the buttons, but the idea is this:

1. By using the above piece of code, the parent window (Main) will be blocked, so it's not possible to click on the other buttons to open the dialogs.
2. Prevent the application from opening the dialogs which are already opened.

Comment: Your question is a bit obscure, let me see if I can clear it up. You want to open dialog windows, avoid to open those windows more than once, and in the meantime keep allowing interaction with the main window, right? Just to be clear, what's the purpose of those dialogs? Are you sure you don't need a QDockWidget instead?

Comment: have you tried ".setEnabled(False)" for disabling the mainwindow and also buttons? and on the closing of a dialog, enable them back for selection.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in the main window you can create functions that open their own window for example:

main window file:

```
def open_add_user_window(self):
    # import the class of window dialog that you create, example:
    from new_user_dialog import NewUserDialog # the class you create
    # Create a variable to store the object of the NewUserDialog class
    # in this case self means the instances of the main window
    window = NewUserDialog(self)  
    # then call the method show() of the object window
    window.show()
```

New User window file (child window):

```
# in the constructor:
# parent is the parameter that stored the main window instance 
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    # with super call the constructor of the QDialog class an passed like argument the 
    #parent
    super().__init__(parent)
    # This is important if you don't put this code the child window will appear like 
    #sticked on the main window.
    self.setWindowFlag(Qt.Window)
```